# BOINC exclusive applications aren't triggering a suspend

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, visual-studio, boinc

I have BOINC running 24/7 and want to have it temporarily suspend while I am compiling large Visual Studio projects to speed things up. As things currently stand, the compiler and BOINC seem to fight for CPU access as BOINC wants to use all CPU time that isn't being used. I have however noticed that if I suspend BOINC manually, I get noticeably faster compile times.

I added the below processes to the exclusive application list which should detect the process name when it is running and suspend BOINC while the process is active. This does not happen but I have confirmed that the processes are running.

It appears that this function is more geared to games or applications that run for a while rather than these processes of which there are many instances that run and exit rapidly. I tried adding firefox.exe to test it out but even after several minutes it still did not recognize the process.

Is there something I am missing? How can I get BOINC to automatically suspend activity while VS is compiling?

[image: exclusive applications]

Running 7.2.28 x64 on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One BOINC restart later... It works flawlessly.

I'm not sure if that is intended but I don't think any other option/setting change requires a restart.

Is there a way to make a change to the exclusive applications list without requiring a restart?

Comment: The settings stick until a restart or a work load is finished and it checks in with the server.

Comment: This should be a comment on @Back2Basics answer.  And, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you use Boinc for the IBM World Community grid.  Log in on the World Community Grid Homepage https://secure.worldcommunitygrid.org/index.jsp
in the top right corner of the screen you will see "settings" click that.
On the next page that pops up you will see "device manager" -> "device profiles"
click on your registered device and you will be able to change the profile for the device by clicking "Edit Device Profiles" and assigning it to your machine.

Take a look around and feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: I would then have to do that one by one for each project of which I support many.

Comment: You don't have to customize for each application.  You could control the processor speed as a whole.  The questions to focus on are:  Do work while computer is in use?,Do work on my graphics card while computer is in use?, Do work only after computer is idle for: x minutes